# Users can login to Website from wp-admin prior to confirmation email

Tags: wp-admin

I have a wordpress website that has an account sign-up/login system.

When a user creates an account from the website's signup page (not the wp-admin page), he has to confirm the email link (in his mail inbox) prior to being able to login.

However, if the user goes to mywebsite.com/wp-admin, he is able to login and access website's resources as a logged in user without having to confirm his email.

I suppose disabling access to wp-admin is not an option as it will create issues since wp-admin is required for proper functioning of the website.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: We’ll how is the email confirmation implemented? It sounds like something custom, but there’s no code so I don’t know how anyone could help. Or is it a plugin?

Comment: Its a custom theme. Not sure to be honest.

Comment: You will likely need to consult whoever built the theme/plugin/site (or hire a freelancer)